# Changing template type of a variable at runtime

Tags: c++, templates

I am having an issue writing a state machine that would switch a template-based variable during the execution. Currently, the implementation is as follows:

```
template <typename TemplateT>
class InnerClass {
  void foo();
}

class StateMachine {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<InnerClass<ParticularType>> inner;

  void someMethod() {
    ...
    inner->foo();
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to generalize this implementation so that `StateMachine` would have a member that would be changing the `inner` variable to different template-based type:

```
void StateMachine::changeState(int state) {
  switch(state) {
  case 0:
    inner.reset(new InnerClass<ParticularType0>());
    break; 
  case 1:
    inner.reset(new InnerClass<ParticularType1>());
    break; 
  case 2:
    inner.reset(new InnerClass<ParticularType2>());
    break;
  ...
  default:
    assert();
  }
}
```

I know that templates can only be used when the type is known at compile-time, hence, most likely, there should be another approach that I am unaware of. Could you please point out some ideas that can be applied here? Are there any other approaches besides using the creation of a templateless interface to the `InnerClass`:

```
class InnerClassInterface {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}

template <typename TemplateT>
class InnerClass : InnerClassInterface {
  virtual void foo() override;
}
```

Comment: The way you proposed is basically the way to solve it.  If for whatever reason you don't want a polymorphic solution, then you would need to drastically change your design.  I don't think anyone can really advise you on that, given the nature of your question is fairly abstract.  I suppose if all of the types are known, then you could use `std::variant` instead and avoid using templates for the "Inner" state itself.  Seems a bit overkill.  Actually, your own solution seems a bit overkill.  Hard to really know why the state machine is written this way.  With no specification, who can say?

Comment: maybe you could check out Sean Parent's talk "Inheritance is the base class of evil" for inspiration.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail what your core problem is? If you want to avoid vtable solution, you can take `std::variant` without using any base class types. OK. But in any kind of solution all types must be known at compile time. I don't catch the point what "compile time" means in your case.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence, most likely, there should be another approach that I am unaware of

Unfortunately, there isn't. Just like you said, templates are evaluated at compile-time. Meaning that unless you type out every possible type parameter for `InnerClass`, like you're doing in the switch statement, there would be no way for the compiler to know which instances of the `InnerClass` template to instantiate.

You would most likely be better off changing your design completely and using some form of polymorphism.

But if you really want to preserve this design, one solution could be to put the the different versions of `ParticularType` into specialized class templates. I have renamed `ParticularType` to `State` and changed the different versions of it to some state names since I assume the `ParticularType`s are meant to represent states.

```
// states.h
enum
{
    STATE_WALKING,
    STATE_RUNNING,
    STATE_SHOOTING
    ...
};
```

```
// state.h
class StateBase
{
public:
    // Insert what your states actually do here
    //        |
    //        V
    virtual void someStateFunc() = 0;
};

template<int I>
class State
{
};

template<>
class State<STATE_WALKING> : public StateBase
{
public:
    // Code for walking state
    void someStateFunc() override
    {
        ...
    }
};

template<>
class State<STATE_RUNNING> : public StateBase
{
public:
    //Code for running state
    void someStateFunc() override
    {
        ...
    }
};

template<>
class State<STATE_SHOOTING> : public StateBase
{
    // Code for shooting state
    ...
};

...
```

In the code in your example you declared `inner` as being of type `std::unique_ptr<InnerClass<ParticularType>>`. This would fail to compile since you try to assign `unique_ptr`s of type `InnerClass<ParticularType0>` and `InnerClass<ParticularType1>` to `inner` inside `changeState`. This is easy to fix though, you just need a base class for `InnerState` to inherit from.

Here's what `InnerClass` and `StateMachine` would look like:

```
class InnerClassBase
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    ...
};

template<typename T>
class InnerClass : public InnerClassBase
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        ...
    }
};

class StateMachine {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<InnerClassBase> inner;

    void someMethod() {
      ...
      inner->foo();
      ...
    }

    template<int S>
    void changeState() {
        inner.reset(new InnerClass<State<S>>());
    }
};
```

and call it like so:

```
#include "states.h"

...

if(some_condition)
{
    stateMachine.changeState<STATE_SHOOTING>();
}
...
```

Every time you want to add a new state, you just add a new specialization to `State`.